# How can I save zeppelin notebook from a docker?

Tags: docker, containers, apache-zeppelin

I am using a docker-container for spark-zeppelin. The docker image was fund here,
https://github.com/Gmousse/docker-zeppelin-python3

I can start an image and work using this command,

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 gmousse/docker-zeppelin-python3
```

To be able to communicate with the host, I have mounted some paths to host with volume flag like this,

```
docker run -it -v /cephfs:/cephfs -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 gmousse/docker-zeppelin-python3
```

it works fine. Now to mount the zeppelin working directory I added this,

```
docker run -it -v /cephfs:/cephfs -v my_path_on_host:/zeppelin -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 gmousse/docker-zeppelin-python3
```

And this does not run.

In this command actually it is looking for a zeppelin.sh file in /zeppelin and fails.

Any idea, how can I mount a local volume, and be able to save zeppelin notebook on the host?

Thank you for your time, in advance...

Answer (score 2):

It is very handy to store notebooks on local file system especially under version control.

So you need to mount only notebook folder, but you tried to mount whole zeppelin folder and on start container could not find zeppelin files.

Correct mount examples:

```
docker run \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    -v /home/user/zeppelin_notebooks:/zeppelin/notebook \
    apache/zeppelin:0.8.0

docker run \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/zeppelin_notebooks,target=/zeppelin/notebook \
    --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.8.0
```

Comment: Thank you @Sonique for your answer. In the second example, what does, --rm --name ... part do?

Comment: `--rm` - remove container after exit, useful when you do not want to produce a lot of containers (you can see all of them with `docker ps -a`) , `--name` will set provided name, not the random one, so you can easily refer to you container for example `docker exec -it zeppelin bash` or `docker start zeppelin`

Answer (score 1):

for My apache zeppelin docker hosted on window 10, the pwd is /opt/zeppelin,  the default path for notebooks is /opt/zeppelin/notebook, so I mount my window path as below, Therefore, All notebooks are being save in "C:/Zeppelin/notebook"

docker run -p 8080:8080 -v C:/Zeppelin/Data/:/opt/zeppelin/Data/ -v C:/Zeppelin/notebook:/opt/zeppelin/notebook --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.10.0